# Exercise 1.16 in Brezis's Functional analysis:

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, proof-verification

Let $E =\ell^1$ so that $E^* = \ell^\infty.$ Consider $N = c_0 = \{x= (x_k): \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}x_k = 0\}$ as a closed subspace of $E^*$. Determine 
$$N^\bot=\{x\in E : \langle f, x\rangle = 0 \quad \forall f\in N \}$$
and 
$$N^{\bot\bot}=\{f\in E^* : \langle f, x\rangle = 0 \quad \forall x\in N^\bot \}.$$

Check that $N^{\bot\bot} \ne N^\bot$ ?

Comment: I think you have written the exercise incorrectly: of course $N^{\perp\perp}\ne N^{\perp}$: the first one lives in $\ell^\infty$, the second one in $\ell^1$.

Comment: No functional analysis needed for this -- compute each quantity with your bare hands.

Comment: I am not sure $N^\bot = \{0\}$ ? And I do not find $N^{\bot\bot}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an example of a subspace $N$ where $N^{\perp\perp}\ne N$ - which can hold only for an infinite dimension subspace.

**Hint:** Consider the sequences $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots),\ \ e_2=(0,1,0,\dots),\ \ e_3=(0,0,1,0,\dots),$ etc.

> All of them are in $N=c_0$, and for any sequence $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ we have $\langle e_n,a\rangle = a_n$. 
>  It follows that $N^\perp=\{0\}$ indeed. 
>  Then $N^{\perp\perp}=\{0\}^\perp=E^*$.